# Проблема с apt/apt-get

Tags: debian

Стояла система 3 года (Debian 10) пока не начал активно баловаться питоном меняя версии. После перестал работать apt и apt-get. Отправился гуглить траблу. Ничего интересного не нашел для решения проблемы или хотя бы намеки. Может вы поможете прояснить ситуации пожалуйста.

````
Установлено или удалено не до конца 4 пакетов.
Необходимо скачать 0 B/1 522 kB архивов.
После данной операции объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 139 kB.
Хотите продолжить? [Д/н] y
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f0f761ec740 (most recent call first):
Aborted
E: Порождённый процесс /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10 вернул код ошибки (1)
E: Failure running script /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10```
````

Comment: приложите к вопросу (нажав [edit]) вывод `$ python --version`

Answer (score 0):

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'` это криво скомпиленный питон кстановлен в систему. Попробуй почистить /usr/local/bin  /usr/local/lib вручную и в следующий раз не запускай `make install` - только `make altinstall`